# Facebook XFBML like button will not resize width - using Joomla and K2

Tags: facebook, width, facebook-like, xfbml, joomla-k2

I just installed the Facebook Like button XFBML plugin on my blog site, which uses K2 and Joomla (I copied the code directly from facebook developers.)  The problem is that the plugin is too wide - it's the default 450px wide.  Even when I enter 400px, and redo it, it stays 450 px wide.  I can't seem to get it to resize for some reason. This is a big problem, because the right side of the comment box is hidden (I have a column on the ride hand side that covers it.)  So, you can't push the "post" button. I've searched google and your database, but I can't find any posts about a similar problem. And I'm not sure where to go for help. Here is a link to an article on my site so you can see what I mean:

http://www.artdotlife.com/art/studio-blog/entertaining-baby/item/148-if-snow-white-and-the-seven-dwarfs-were-released-today-it-would-incite-mobs-of-angry-mothers-little-people-and-screenwriters-here%E2%80%99s-why

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your using Joomla, no problem.  When I look at the code all I see is .  Using Firebug I can see that the comments plugin is runnin at 550px.

When you edit this module do you turn the editor off?  I would try that and make sure you add the width variable to the comments tag as it's not showing up.

Comments also requires an href tag to work properly if I'm not mistaken.  Not the issue with the width but just a heads up.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I just saw this.... Not sure I'm able to follow you though. I use the backend of joomla to do all my editing. And my coding skills are limited to copying and pasting into the "custom html module" thing, which uses a WYSIWYG editor. Maybe that's the problem? Because when I toggle my editor window back and forth from the html, the code disappears.  I haven't been sure what that means. I'm hesitant to edit my files directly unless I know exactly what to do because I don't want to mess things up.    So, I don't know how to turn the editor off.  Could you tell me?  Thanks!